# Spring data jpa: findBy property hangs on "Starting beans in phase 2147483647" in Junit test

Tags: junit, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a problem in my junit test while accessing my spring data jpa repository.
I'm using the findByProperty functionality. But it hangs while accessing it.

My Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TC_ORDER")
public class Order extends AbstractCatalog{

        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_SID")
    private Long id;

}
```

My Abstractcatalog:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractCatalog {

   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "CODE",updatable=false)
    private String code;

    public void setCode(final String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

}
```

Spring data jpa repository:

```java
public interface OrderRepository extends AbstractCatalogRepository<Order> {
}
```

AbstractCatalogRepository:

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractCatalogRepository<T extends AbstractCatalog> extends
  CustomRepository<T, Serializable> {
     T findByCode(String code);
}
```

The junit test:

```java
@Inject
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Test
    public void orderCatalogisComplete() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(orderRepository); // OK
        Assert.assertEquals(18,orderRepository.count()); //OK       
    }
    @Test
    public void searchForSL1InDb(){

        Order sl1 = orderRepository.findByCode("SL-1"); // HANGS HERE
         Assert.assertNotNull(sl1);
    }
}
```

This is the relevant resulting logging:

```java
...preceding spring integration logging (also used in my project)...
13:49:19.828 INFO  o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter start 357 - started org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter@1202f4d
13:49:19.828 INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start 334 - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
```

And there it hangs..

Comment: Where exactly does it "hang"? Could you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: There is no stacktrace. There's just the info logging of org.springframework (debug logging gives no extra's):
13:49:19.828 INFO  o.s.i.m.IntegrationMBeanExporter start 357 - started org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter@1202f4d
13:49:19.828 INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start 334 - Starting beans in phase 2147483647

Comment: Seeing this in a deployment of my app as well, however, only one box out of ~200 has it.  Did you find a solution/cause?

Comment: I am stuck at the same state, it looks like Spring is hung, with no stack trace. 2016-10-22 00:55:31.239  INFO 58576 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647

Comment: please let me know if you've found the cause or what are we doing wrong.

Comment: it seems like removing ActiveMQ dependency from my POM has solved the above given issue, but it has further stuck at 2016-10-22 01:10:41.503  INFO 60218 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue, if you are logging elsewhere, check your other log location as there might be another message from a component that makes the build hang - in my case it was cobertura.

Answer (score 0):

add below given dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```